# "DateTimeField()" is not editable in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-admin

I have a blog and I post many articles. Each article has a date of publication, and sometimes I have to edit this date. Everything running on the Django admin panel and I never encountered any 500 error since I decided to add the DateTimeField in my admin.py.

The issue is, Django cannot edit the DateTimeField and it returns :

> Internal Server Error: /admin/wall/articles/62/change/
>
> FieldError at /admin/wall/articles/62/change/ 'date' cannot be
> specified for Articles model form as it is a non-editable field. Check
> fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ArticlesAdmin.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

models.py:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=False, verbose_name="Description pour les partages sur les réseaux sociaux")
    subtitle = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, verbose_name="Sous-titre")
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name="Tag")
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, verbose_name="Sous-catégorie", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='media/articles/', validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Image de présentation")
    image_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Description pour cette image")
    image_legende = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Légende pour cette images")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur")
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Publié")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('read', kwargs={'post':self.id, 'slug':slugify(self.title)})
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
class ArticlesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'title', 'author', 'published', 'update')

    fieldsets = (
        ('Général', {
            'fields': ('title', 'author', 'published', 'tag')
            }),
        ('Date de publication', {
            'fields': ('date',)}),
        ('Choisir une image de présentation (700px de largeure et 320px de hauteur', {
            'fields': ('image',)}),
        ('Description de l\'image', {
            'fields': ('image_description',)}),
        ('Légende de l\'image', {
            'fields': ('image_legende',)}),
        ('Sous-titre de l\'article', {
            'fields': ('subtitle',)}),                  
        ('Contenu de l\'article', {
            'fields': ('text', 'description')}),
    )
        
admin.site.register(Articles, ArticlesAdmin)
```

Comment: you can not update the date field if auto_now_add=True

Comment: maybe have something to do with the fact that the auto_add_now = True

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`auto_now_add=True` makes that field not editable.
You should disable `auto_now_add` (`auto_now_add=False`) and implement that behaviour yourself (for example, in `save()` method of Articles `self.date = timezone.now()`).

Little remark about naming: you should name your model in single form, not plural (Article instead of Articles)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that I have made a mistake in my naming :)

Comment: I removed the "auto_now_add" field and to replace it, I did this "date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de création", default=timezone.now(), null=False)" Thank you

Comment: hi can you let me know if i want to save the date using a user input instead of timezone.now i.e. for the self.date = timezone.now() line what needs to be used instead of timezone.now()

Comment: use `default=timezone.now` instead of `default=timezone.now()`

Comment: for those wondering what the import is: from django.utils import timezone

Comment: What if someone just needs to test and edit created date for testing purpose, is Django that not flexible with testing?

Comment: @Vedmant You can always update the timestamp directly on the database, skipping any parts of the `save` method. e.g. `Article.object.filter(id=123).update(created_at=timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=15))`

Answer (score 0):

[auto_now=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) or [auto_now_add=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) makes [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) `editable=False`.

The doc says below in [DateField.auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> As currently implemented, setting `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` to `True` will cause the field to have `editable=False` and `blank=True` set.

And, even if you set [editable=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#editable) with `auto_now=True` or `auto_now_add=True` to them as shown below, they are actually `editable=False`:

```py
datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)
```

So to make them `editable=True`, just remove `auto_now=True` or `auto_now_add=True` from them as shown below:

```py
datetime = models.DateTimeField()
date = models.DateField()
time = models.TimeField()
```